# Pass Image from UITabBarController to subview (Swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode6

I am using `Xcode 6` with `swift`.

I am trying to pass an `image / UIImage` from my `UITabBarController` to one of the subviews (tabs). The Image itself is being passed to the `UITabBarController` using the loadImage function (which is in return called by another UIViewController during `prepareForSegue`).

```
//this is the tab bar controller
class DesignerTabBarController : UITabBarController{

    var pickedImage : UIImage = UIImage() //empty image

    var VC1: DesignerTabController = DesignerTabController.alloc()

        func loadImage(passedImage: UIImage){
            pickedImage = passedImage
            println(pickedImage) // image is accessible from here
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
            println(pickedImage) //image is accessible from here
            VC1.pickedImageView.image = pickedImage // this line gives "unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping optional"

        }


}

//this is the `UIViewcontroller` I want display the image (inside pickedImageView)
class DesignerTabController : UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var pickedImageView: UIImageView!

}
```

I realize that my way of passing the image from the `UITabBarController` to the sub-view will not work, even though when there are no syntax errors displayed within Xcode (it suggested pickedImageView when I started typing so I think I am really close to the solution).

If it's not possible passing data from my `UITabBarController` to the (first) subview, how can I pass data directly to the first subview? As I explained above, I am passing the image from another view using prepareForSegue. Does prepareForSegue directly to the first view work in my case?

Thank you very much for any suggestions, I'll try them and get back with my findings.

Comment: Did you try to put breakpoints in your code and check variables state? For example define some `- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image` in your VC class and check processing.

Comment: please see above, I am using swift. Also, I am trying to print the image in two locations (see above code), and in both locations I can see image dimensions in console (which indicates that the image is correctly accessible from this location). I believe the way I am trying to pass the image to the subview is causing the error. Thank you for reply.

Comment: Does VC1 accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by using viewDidLayoutSubviews() instead of viewDidLoad()

see below code for my working solution:

```
class DesignerTabController : UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var pickedImageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var labelTest: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

}

class DesignerTabBarController : UITabBarController{

var pickedImage : UIImage = UIImage()

func loadImage(passedImage: UIImage){
    pickedImage = passedImage
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    if let controller = viewControllers![0] as? DesignerTabController{
        controller.pickedImageView.image = pickedImage
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your tab bar controller has `viewControllers` property. Just iterate through it check which controller is kind of class you need.

```
func passImage(passedImage: UIImage)
{
  if viewControllers!.isEmpty{
    return
  }
  for index in 0...viewControllers!.count{
    if let controller = viewControllers[index] as? DesignerTabController
      controller.pickedImageView.image = passedImage
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. I added this to my DesignerTabBarController, but it seems viewControllers is not accessible. I have also added some curly brackets. See my error: http://i.imgur.com/eSxbLSX.png

Comment: Thanks again Astoria, but it still did not work. Please see my code and console debugging here (seems we are back to same problem like with my original code): http://i.imgur.com/4aM9jUp.png

Comment: @LucaV. try to set a breakpoint on `controller.pickedImageView.image = passedImage` line and check which of the `controller`, `pickedImageView` are nil? Did you connect pickedImageView outlet to real control?

Comment: control is linked properly. controller returns correct id, but controller.pickedImageView returns nil. strange...

Comment: I suspect the following: When passImage is called from UITabBarController, the subview is not fully loaded yet (hence, the linked pickedImageView returns nil). Now the question is: How to delay it so it will be called after the subview is fully loaded?